# lxml.html.fromstring returns <Element html at 0x49e4d50>

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

so i am building my first web-scraper. To start things of, here is the code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

page = requests.get("https://amazon.de/gp/product/B071D5LKQC")
print(page.content)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
print(tree)
price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()')
print(price)
```

Im getting the content of the site as a string, but to use xpath on it i need to convert it to html. But when i enter:

```
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
```

i get the following error message:

```
<Element html at 0x3a44d50>
```

and of course the array is empty [].

why is that? It seems like in every tutorial they do exactly the same and it works perfectly. Thanks in advance!

ADDITION: It seems to work on other websites. So its either a wrong xpath or something with amazon itself.

Comment: It seems to work on other websites. So its either a wrong xpath or something with amazon itself.

Comment: Amazon may use JavaScript to add HTML and requests/lxml can't run JavaScript. Or Amazon recognized that it script, not real human and send different content. `print(page.content)` to see what you get - maybe there is some useful message or warning. You can also open web browser, turn off JavaScript and load your URL to see what requests/lxml can see.

Comment: You were completly right. I looked into the string and it says that they identify myself as a bot. Is there any way to slip under the radar? Like using proxies and user-agents? Or is there no way to scrap amazon in 2019?

Comment: people use Python with Selenium which let you control read web browser and it will run JavaScript. It also load other files - css, images - so it behave more like human. requests+lxml doesn't load css, images. You can also use random delays between clicks. People can't visit 10 pages in 1 second, requests+lxml can do this. People visit pages with different delays in random order. Script can load 10 pages in 1 second and mostly it visit pages in the same order.

Comment: Should i directly go for selenium or try my luck with lxml? I mean selenium is a lot slower and takes up a lot more resources. Is selenium viable for a bot that scrapes 24/7? On the other hand i dont want to waste time trying to get lxml to work when it never will.

Comment: problem is not `lxml` but rather `requests`. if page uses JavaScript then you can't get HTML with `requests`. You may have to check all requests from browser to server to find URL used by JavaScript to get data. If you have it then you can get data - mostly as JSON so you don't have to use lxml. But it can encrypt data and you may have to dig in JavaScript code to see how it is encrypted and then you have to create code in Python which can encrypt it. With Selenium you don't have to do it. Maybe Selenium works slower but you may faster create working program.

Comment: thank you so much, i think ill go with selenium then. Any suggestion how many requests per minute are ok? Could i go higher than 5 or will this result in a ban?